Trying to install Pi-Apps but held dependencies not fixable
So I'm trying to install Pi-Apps on my Pi5 but after running the install command I get
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-freedesktop : Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (= 1.74.0-3) but 2.82.1-1 is to be installed
 gir1.2-pango-1.0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.50.12+ds-1) but 1.54.0+ds-2 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.50.12+ds-1) but 1.54.0+ds-2 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.50.12+ds-1) but 1.54.0+ds-2 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.50.12+ds-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk3-perl : Depends: libglib-object-introspection-perl but it is not installable
 software-properties-common : Depends: packagekit
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Pi-Apps dependencies failed to install and so the Pi-Apps install has been aborted. Before Pi-Apps can be installed you must solve any errors above.


I tried installing the dependencies but it said they were already presentfor example
libpango-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.54.0+ds-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I tried checking for held packages with sudo apt-mark showhold but that showed nothing
I tried sudo apt full-upgrade but it installed nothing new and didn't work after
I checked the dependencies of the dependencies but they were installed
Is there maybe something wrong with my sources.list or do I have the wrong versions of the dependencies and how can I fix it?

The issue seems to be with libglib-object-introspection-perl. Try installing it.

@TheMaster it gives me the same error that I can't install it because I have held packages but checking for held packages does not result in any output The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgirepository-1.0-1 : Breaks: libglib-object-introspection-perl (< 0.051-2~) but 0.049-3 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
